# Why a #Name? error for Time control on Access form please?

Tags: forms, ms-access, time, default, short

I’ve a timesheet Access DB, using a TimeFrom & TimeTo structure (Short Time formats). 
A query returns the MaxTimeTo for current date & employee, also in Short Time format. 
Attempting to use this qry result as the frmTimesheet default for TimeFrom on New Record, yet met with #Name? error. 
Any suggestions are most appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*DateTime* values carries no format, but the *DefaultValue* must be a string, thus format your time value:

```
frmTimesheet!TimeFrom.DefaultValue = Format(MaxTime, "\#hh\:nn\:ss\#")
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav! Some poor functioning & resultant tweaking proved a better solution was to .SetValue with a DLookup("field","qry") and it happened to have no formatting issues yay! Most grateful for advice :)